# Remove the following redirect chain if possible from Google

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, server, adsense, pingdom

We have recently started using **Google Analytics** and activated Google Re Marketting on **Analytics panel**

Now we are seeing the following error messages when testing with **Pingdom**:

Its says Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?v=1& ... 
https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect?v=1&a ... 
https://www.google.com/ads/ga-audiences?v=1&aip ... 
https://www.google.se/ads/ga-audiences?v=1&aip= ...
```

How Can we fix this
[image]

Using PingDom, We just scored an "F" from "Minimizing Redirects" ,
How can I fix the redirect chain that was pointed out to us by the pingdom tool?

> **PS**: We are not locally hosting the Analytics.js

Comment: Probably by disabling advertising features in Google Analytics (which will reduce the features, e.g. you won't have demographics). Advertising features use doubleclick code rather than analytics.js, hence the redirect.

Comment: We also tried what you suggested , We **disabled** Advertising Reporting features( Audience Demographics and Interests Reporting ) but still no luck , Are we suppose to wait or something ? Thank you for responding.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: are you over https or http?

Comment: @SergChernata We were not able to figure this out yet , sorry for the delay though :D

Comment: @KemenPaulosPlaza We 've used it with http and also https , Currently we are using "//" , apparently nothing seems to work with this

Comment: It looks like pingdom is using Google Analytics too and also looks like they have solved the problem. Would you like to try and ask them? Then we all have figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off BOTH `Remarketing` and `Advertising Reporting` features in data collection settings:

Admin --> Property --> Tracking Info --> Data Collection